# Jetty Server logs getting printed to STDOUT instead of log file

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, restlet

I'm building a REST service with Spring/Restlet/Jetty/Maven.

I have added "jetty-logging.properties" to the classpath.

#### jetty-logging.properties file contains:

org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog

org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO

org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.IGNORED=false

#### Also log4j.properties file is in the classpath.

All the logs are added to the log file except the jetty server logs which are getting printed to STDOUT. I want the server logs to go to the same file specified in log4j.properties.

#### Jetty plugin config in pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <!--<webXml>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/web.xml</webXml> -->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Rushi